# Binding an object to an object using jquery $.data

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm wondering if there's a way to use jquery $.data to bind button1 element to button2 so that when I click button2
I can access the button1 object and extract attributes etc.

The binding code I have is in the following function, this is called by clicking button1 and the this object is passed in as:

button1:

```
$(".acc-offer-clicked").click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     getCourierList(this);
});

function getCourierList(obj) {

     //Bind the accept button to the choose-courier button
     $.data($("#choose_courier"), "accept", obj); 

}
```

later when button1 is clicked I hope to extract button2 as

```
$("#choose_courier").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var acceptbutton = $(this).data("accept");  
});
```

At this point accept-button is *undefined*. I've been able to bind `{}` type objects before but I've never tried with an actual element. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose the problem is that

```
$.data($("#choose_courier"), "accept", obj);
```

binds data to a **newly created jQuery object** `$("#choose_courier")`. Then, when you try to retrieve it, you create **another object**, which does not have any `data` associated.

[Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) gives the following `$.data` signature: `jQuery.data( element, key, value )`. Not **jQuery object**, but **element**.

For resolve your problem you may use [`$(selector).data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/).

I've included both variants in this sample [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vzKXG/), check it out.